# Integrating Active Directory in my asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory

In my website i want to use active directory users for authentication. how can i do this.

Comment: If you do a google search for Active Directory and asp.net you will find a ton of resources on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do programmatic validation of credentials against Active Directory, you should use the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` classes that are available in .NET 3.5.

Read the [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) in the January 2008 issue of MSDN Magazine for more info. *NOTE: only CHM download*

For validating credentials, you'd have to create a principal context - either a machine (single server) or domain (network) and then call the `.ValidateCredentials()` method on it:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");

if(ctx.ValidateCredentials(userName, password))
{
    // user is validated
}
```

Pretty simple, isn't it?? This works great if your users need to log in using a form where they enter username and password and you can grab these to check their account.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify Windows Authentication in your web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
</system.web>
```

Then set up allow/deny blocks to specify users who have access, etc.

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="AuthorizedADGroup" />
  <allow users="AllowedUserName" />
  <deny users="*" />
  <deny users="?"/>      
</authorization>
```